# Quelle est la traduction de « article of impeachment » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie, droit-et-justice

> Pelosi signs **[article](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/article#English) of [impeachment](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impeachment)** against Trump.

S'agit-il de l'acte d'accusation (*LeFigaro*), de la mise en accusation (*Le Monde*), de la mise en examen (*BBC*), ou de l'article d'*impeachment* (LaPresse) qui est signé ? Ces locutions sont-elles toutes adéquates et laquelle préfère-t-on, et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3):

> Nancy Pelosi signe un acte de mise en accusation pour destitution à l'encontre de Donald Trump.

On peut aussi parler de *résolution de mise en accusation* mais on s'éloigne un peu de l'usage américain.

Je ne retiendrai pas *mise en examen* (qui en France a remplacé *inculpation* en 1993) car elle est prononcée par un juge d'instruction et concerne la justice ordinaire alors qu'un président de la république est jugé par le parlement réuni en [Haute Cour](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haute_Cour_(France)) (article 68 de la constitution).

Comment: Un bon équilibre de l'analyse entre l'analogie et l'usage...

Comment: +1 pour la précision que l'impeachment n'est pas une procédure judiciaire. Cette distinction est centrale et est la réponse à beaucoup de questions sur le sujet sur Politics SE: l'impeachment est une procédure politique, pas judiciaire.

Comment: @Sacha En substance il s'agit d'un procès, ad hoc, mais amorcé par l'assemblée législative et qui se tient au sénat avec des [règles](https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/resources/pdf/3_1986SenatesImpeachmentRules.pdf) etc. qui lui sont propres quoique clairement « analogous to the bringing of an indictment by a grand jury » ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_in_the_United_States)) et présidé par le juge en chef le la cour suprême, sauf que la seule conséquence possible est la destitution, avec le concours de 2/3 des sénateurs... Il ne s'agit pas de droit pénal.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie La plupart des définitions de "procès" que je trouve impliquent une procédure judiciaire et se rapportent au droit, ce que l'impeachment n'est pas. Par extension, il est possible que "procès" puisse désigner des procédures extrajudiciaires, mais ça n'a pas l'air d'être le sens commun.
L'impeachment serait plus à rapprocher d'une motion de censure telle qu'elle existe en France (même si elle diffère beaucoup) que d'un procès.
Je ne trouve pas mention dans la page Wikipédia que la Cour Suprême soit impliquée dans l'impeachment, et de ce que j'en sais, ce n'est pas le cas.

Comment: @Sacha Le juge en chef (*Chief justice*) de la Cour suprême préside l'assemblée qui décide de la destitution d'un président des États-Unis, mais la décision est en effet bien politique (majorité des 2/3 du parlement, pas une décision de magistrats).

Comment: @Sacha C'est un truc d'[équilibre dans la séparation des pouvoirs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_powers#Checks_and_balances), partie intégrante du système constitutionnel américain « constitutionnal system based on checks and balances ». Ce pouvoir apparaît directement dans la constitution mais ça ne se rapporterait pas au droit haahhaha. Ta définition du droit est alambiquée, c'est elle qui est « politique ». Évidemment que ce n'est pas comme un procès devant un juge dans une cour de droit commun, c'est devant des sénateurs au sénat, mais un procès devant jury, ça existe.

Comment: Je comprends que les étiquettes sont réconfortantes mais un peu plus de pragmatisme est de mise. Par ailleurs sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_(%C3%89tats-Unis)) on trouve : « L’impeachment est destiné à mettre en cause la responsabilité pénale individuelle du titulaire d'un siège gouvernemental, et non une responsabilité politique. Il n'est pas assimilable à une motion de censure, incompatible avec le régime présidentiel et la conception américaine de la séparation des pouvoirs ». Donc pas pénal au sens traditionnel mais néanmoins ; surtout pas « politique ».

Comment: Un recours constitutionnel n'est pas « politique » parce qu'il ne s'exerce pas devant un tribunal de droit commun. Le fait que des politiques (représentants) amorcent la procédure, et que d'autres (sénateurs), en décident, ne fait pas de la procédure ou de leur décision une procédure ou une décision « politique ». Amorcée et décidée par des politiques, certainement. Sui generis et ad hoc, certainement. Oui oui la branche judiciaire non, j'ai compris. Mais qu'est-ce que ça fait. Les autres pouvoirs ne sont pas « politiques », ils sont exécutifs et législatifs dans une classification trad.

Comment: Pour moi, la classification du tout comme « politique », voire pire, comme du non-droit, relève de l'incurie, délégitime la procédure et assimile ce qu'on reproche au président à un délit d'opinion. Or ce n'est pas le cas et ce n'est surtout pas un effet de toge parlementaire.