# Comment traduire « (to sign) the engrossment of the [bill etc.] » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie, droit-et-justice

> Today, in a bipartisan way, the House demonstrated that no one is
> above the law, not even the President of the United States, that
> Donald Trump is a clear and present danger to our country, and that,
> once again, we honored our oath of office to protect and defend the
> Constitution of the United States, so help us God.
>
> And, now, I sadly and with a heart broken over what this means to our
> country – of a President who would incite insurrection – will sign the
> **engrossment** of the [Article of Impeachment](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/44240/25619).
>
> [[Nancy Pelosi lors de la signature de...](https://youtu.be/5PUV2XvI5qs) / [texte officiel](https://www.speaker.gov/newsroom/11321-1),
> je souligne ]

Le terme *engrossment* est relié au processus législatif aux États-Unis, c'est généralement le « formal reprinting of the bill in the form upon which the chamber will vote final passage ».<sup>1</sup>

Dans différents domaines on a en français des termes techniques employés pour des documents à l'aspect formel etc. comme [*expédition*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=ENGROSSMENT&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), [*grosse*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grosse/1) ou [*ampliation*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ampliation), plus utiles à la réflexion qu'à la traduction ici...

---

Dans une traduction des propos qui ressemblerait à « (je ... vais signer/signe) le/la [engrossment] de [article of impeachment] » ou autrement, comment doit-on traduire le terme *engrossment*, le cas échéant ; pourquoi ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Dans [*Engrossment, Enrollment, and Presentation of Legislation*](https://www.senate.gov/CRSpubs/82df20bb-1716-414a-bdcd-0bc8eaa11f13.pdf), de R. Eric Petersen, CRS (notes omises, une note reproduite dans le corps du texte ; sur la destitution voir ([ici](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R45769.pdf) et [là](https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/common/briefing/Senate_Impeachment_Role.htm)) :</sub>

<sub><sub>**Engrossment**</sub></sub>

<sub><sub>When either house orders the third reading of a bill, it simultaneously orders the engrossment of the bill. Engrossment is the formal reprinting of the bill in the form upon which the chamber will vote final passage. [In earlier times, such bills were handwritten in very large script, hence the term “engrossment.”] House and Senate Rules require that all bills, amendments, and joint resolutions passed in each chamber must be examinedby the Clerk of the House or Secretary of the Senate, as appropriate. Official engrossed copies are prepared by staff in the Office of the Clerk of the House and the Office of the Secretary of the Senate. The clerk or secretary are required to attest to the accuracy of the engrossed text by signing the measures. The House-engrossed measures, including amendments to bills passed by the Senate, are printed on blue paper; the Senate prints its engrossed measures on white paper. If either chamber later discovers errors in one of its engrossed measures, it may adopt a resolution formally requesting the other chamber to return the engrossed bill or resolution to it for correction.</sub></sub>

<sub><sub>An engrossed bill is “messaged” by the originating house to the other; the second chamber to act attaches the text of whatever amendments it adopts to the original measure it has received from the first.</sub></sub>

---

Comment: **texte définitif d'un projet de loi**; formal reprinting just means the final bill.

Answer (score 1):

En français on dirait, comme ce titre l'indique:

**Le texte définitif du projet de loi** Gazier

[article dans Le Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/1957/02/18/le-texte-definitif-du-projet-de-loi-gazier_2329412_1819218.html)

**Le texte définitif du projet de loi**.

et aussi ici: [un autre article de presse](https://www.banquedesterritoires.fr/les-deputes-adoptent-definitivement-le-projet-de-loi-egalim)

Ce qui coincide avec le sens de l'anglais donné dans la question:

*Engrossment is the formal reprinting of the bill in **the form upon which the chamber will vote final passage**.*

So, it means: the final form of a bill, here, an article in the impeachment procedure.

[US Senate text explaining engrossment](https://www.senate.gov/CRSpubs/82df20bb-1716-414a-bdcd-0bc8eaa11f13.pdf)

Pour la phrase en entier, on dirait donc:
**Je signerai le texte définitif de l'Article de [la procédure de] l'impeachment**.

NB: la traduction d'impeachment est restée impeachment et se trouve comme procédure d'impeachment dans le Collins.  C'est dommage **puisque** le sens est le même qu'empêchement en français.

Answer (score -2):

Salut ^^

J'ai trouvé ça :

1 : the act of engrossing. 2 : the state of being absorbed or occupied : preoccupation.

Pour le p'tit 1 ça veut dire : "the final version of a legal document, especially a deed or statute."

Je pense c'est les deux seules traduction de ce mot :)

Comment: Oui mais comment tu traduis en français « engrossment » dans la phrase « I will sign the engrossment of the Article of Impeachment. ». Comment traduis-tu cette phrase en français ? Tu peux t'appuyer sur ta réponse à l'autre question et utiliser le verbe _signer_ si tu crois que c'est juste. Tu peux partir d'une traduction de DeepL et voir si ça cadre avec une des définitions que tu as identifiées et faire un choix de traduction en expliquant. Merci !

Comment: " Je signerai l'engagement de l'article de destitution." C'est ce que deepl me donne, je ne peux pas te dire plus du pourquoi du comment désoler ^^'

Comment: *Engagement, projet validé* : « [ *J'entérinerai/Je validerai* le projet de loi | *J'intègrerai* l'article (dans la loi) ] de destitution …  » selon les contextes

Comment: Ceci ne répond pas à la question qui demande comment exprimer une idée en français (ce qui est logique sur [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) et non pas une définition en anglais (ce que le PO semble connaître). Par ailleurs quand on dit « j'ai trouvé » il est d'usage de citer ses sources. Et dans la mesure où le site est fréquenté par beaucoup de non francophones qui cherchent à améliorer leur français il vaut mieux éviter des tournures « p'tit ».